# How to iterate last six month(including current) loop without any custom table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want output like follow:

[image]

Currently I am using a table. But I don't want to use this with any table(EXCEPT SYSTEM TABLES). Is it possible?

Query(Using a table):

```
DECLARE @End_date DATETIME
SET @End_Date = DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())

SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(S.ACDATE) AS Mon,CONVERT(CHAR(4),S.ACDATE) AS Month_Name,
    (YEAR(S.ACDATE) % 100) AS Year_No
    FROM SALES as S
    WHERE S.ACDATE < DATEADD(month,MONTH(getdate()),
          DATEADD(year,YEAR(getdate())-1900,0))
    AND S.ACDATE >= DATEADD(month,MONTH(@End_Date)-1,
        DATEADD(year,YEAR(@End_Date)-1900,0))
```

Comment: ... what is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?  Create a calendar table?  Get a date range?  Why do you want a two digit year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @dt DATE = CONVERT(DATE, '05/03/2013', 101)

SELECT MONTH (dt) AS Mon, LEFT (DATENAME (mm, dt), 3) AS Month_Name, YEAR (dt) % 1000 AS Year_No
FROM (
    SELECT DATEADD (mm, -diff, @dt) dt
    FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6))t(diff)
) t
```

Result set is:

```
Mon         Month_Name Year_No
----------- ---------- -----------
4           Apr        13
3           Mar        13
2           Feb        13
1           Jan        13
12          Dec        12
11          Nov        12
```

Comment: It is not working for date '05-03-2013'(Date format MM/DD/YYYY)

Comment: Actually I want last six month+current month

Comment: Ok I got it I have to put(0)